# Clearing the clipboard using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, clipboard

How can the clipboard be cleared using VBScript on Win32?

Comment: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mshta ""about:<head><hta:application showintaskbar=no windowstate=minimize /><script>window.clipboardData.setData('text','');window.close();</script></head>""", 0, False`

Answer (score 8):

It can not be done directly, but you can let an application do the work. This will clear
the clipboard, using the command-line tool [`clip`](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo. >NUL  | clip", 0, True
```

---

Another way is to use applications that have a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) interface and that can manipulate
the clipboard. E.g. Microsoft Word and Internet Explorer.

This will work, using Internet Explorer, but it may throw a user dialog:

```
Set slaveApplication = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
slaveApplication.Navigate("about:blank")
slaveApplication.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "text", ""
slaveApplication.Quit
```

Comment: First one is pretty cool.  The second one you might be able to work around by adding "about:blank" to trusted sites.

Comment: Regarding the first version, `echo off | clip` is a bit simpler than `echo. >NUL | clip` (see https://www.ghacks.net/2016/10/31/three-methods-to-clear-the-windows-clipboard/)