# How to Clear the MS Office Clipboard using VBA code converted to VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

I wanna do a simple script that clears the MS Office Clipboard using some VBA code adapted to VBS code.

I Tried this:

Dim XLapp
Set XLapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

XLapp.CutCopyMode=False

didnt work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing the clipboard using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396109/clearing-the-clipboard-using-vbscript)

Comment: @FlorentB.`CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")`  does not work in VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to writing VBScript then you should download [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/).  It is free to use but well worth the price if you are going to be writing a lot of scripts.  It also comes with HTAEdit.

[image: VbsEdit Screenshot]

[image: VbsEdit Local Window Screenshot]

Using the sample script you can clear the ClipBoard like this:

```
Dim toolkit
Set toolkit = CreateObject("vbsedit.toolkit")
toolkit.PutClipboardText ""
```

Or simple

> CreateObject("vbsedit.toolkit").PutClipboardText ""

**Note:** you can not create a DataObject in VBScript. `CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")` will work in VBA but will fail in VBScript.